# Response.Redirect identified as XSS possible by Fortify

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, xss

My sample MVC .Net code as below . which is identified XSS possible by Fortify tool.

```
string path = "~/sample/index";
if(Url.IsLocalUrl(path)){
Response.Redirect(path , false);
}
```

Pls advise on an alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Server.Transfer(ppath);` in place to get it through.